# InControl - How to Rotate Player Smoothly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, interpolation

I'm using the [InControl input manager](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14695) for my project. I'm using input from the right stick to rotate my player object, but I want the player to be rotated smoothly rather than instantaneously.

Here's my current code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    var device = InputManager.ActiveDevice;

    MoveThePlayer(device.LeftStick.X, device.LeftStick.Y);
    RotateThePlayer(device.RightStick.X, device.RightStick.Y);
}


void MoveThePlayer(float movex, float movey)
{
    body.velocity = new Vector2(movex * speed, movey * speed);
}

void RotateThePlayer(float movex, float movey)
{
    float heading = Mathf.Atan2(movey, movex);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, heading * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
}
```

Comment: please mark my answer as correct or specify what was wrong with my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lerps are your friend.

`transform.Rotate()` your player towards the angle you want by using `Time.deltaTime`

Example:

```
transform.Rotate(0, 0, (angleIWantToBeAt - transform.eulerAngles.z) * Time.deltaTime * speedMultiplier)
```